# how can i serialize all model fields inside model in django

Tags: python, django

I have the model object available inside the django template as `Obj`.

now i want a generic function which can display all fields in and value like this

```
{% for instance in data %}
    {% for field, value in instance.fields.items %}
        {{ field }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried this in Model

```
def objectdata(self):
        return serializers.serialize( "python", self.objects.all() )
```

Then i get the maximum recursion error because it was looping over my this function.

I can't edit the view. is there any way that i can add something in Model only to make that working

Answer (score 0):

Some tips :
If `instance` is a django Model instance, the list of fields is in `instance._meta.fields` . You can use it to walk trough the instance and get the list you want :

```
def objectdata(self):
    k_w = {}
    for field in self._meta.fields :
        k_w[field.name] = self.__getattr__(field.name)

    return k_w
```

Be careful with some field like ForeignKey, ...